Как запустить функцию на python из js?
Задача запустить python функцию при нажатии кнопки (js), но без предварительного запуска python файла, как это работает при использовании eel.
JS
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit')

submitBtn.onclick = function () {
    async function send () {
        let znachenie = document.getElementById('input').value;
        await eel.get_input(znachenie);
    }
    send();
}

Python
import eel

eel.init("web")

@eel.expose
def get_input(znachenie):
   first = znachenie * 10
   print first

При использовании eel необходимо сначала запустить .py, а уже потом работать со страницей. Мне же необходимо обращаться к питону только при нажатии кнопки.
Видел варианты с использованием Flask и других фреймворков, но это избыточно для данного проекта.

JS работает в браузере, python работает на "сервере". Python скрипт не будет работать без запушенного python. Браузер не даст запустить на локальной машине никакой исполняемый файл. Так что либо поднимать полноценный бэк, либо никак.
